# Using Global Actions to Create a child record - MD relationship

Tags: lightning, master-detail, global-actions

Is it possible to use Global Actions in Salesforce to create a Child Record in a Master-Detail Relationship?

I only see the master in the list of Target Objects.

Answer (score 3):

**That is by design.**

According to Salesforce Docs [Quick Action Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_considerations.htm&type=0)

> **Actions to create records for an object that is the detail object in a master-detail relationship must be object-specific, not global.**

[Object-Specific Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview_object_specific.htm&type=0)

When you create an object-specific action, you can choose as a target object only an event, task, or any object that has a parent-child or lookup relationship to the host object. You can create object-specific actions on many objects, including:

- Account
- Campaign
- Case
- Contact
- Custom objects
- Group
- Lead
- Opportunity